# How can I import a folder in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using webpack for my chess project and I have the svgs of the pieces which I don't want to import one by one but rather import the whole folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`require.context`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context)

> `require.context ( folder, recurse, pattern )`
>
> - folder - String - Path to folder to begin scanning for files.
> - recurse - Boolean - Whether to recursively scan the folder.
> - pattern - RegExp - Matching pattern describing which files to include.

#### Array

Create an array of the imported files.

```
const reqSvgs = require.context ( './images', true, /\.svg$/ )
const paths = reqSvgs.keys ()

const svgs = paths.map( path => reqSvgs ( path ) )
```